# content aligned with vertical tab height html, css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help on write HTML code that makes vertical tab and content that appears next to the tab on click.

[image]

[image]

I was able to find vertical tab example codes from other post however I could not find how to align content height and shaded box without hard code. I could not made it responsive when I manually give style of margin-top.

Comment: in order to get the best answer you can, please check out [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to do this. Here is my idea

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:red;
}
.tab {
  position:relative;
}
.tab_title {
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  width:80px;
  background:orange;
  padding:5px 0;
}
.tab_content {
  background:yellow;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:80px;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  padding:5px 20px;
}
.tab:hover .tab_content {
  display:block;
}
.tab:hover .tab_title {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab_title">A</div>
    <div class="tab_content">Content of A<br>long<br>text<br>yeah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab_title">B</div>
    <div class="tab_content">Content of B<br>long<br>text<br>yeah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="tab_title">C</div>
    <div class="tab_content">Content of C<br>long<br>text<br>yeah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```